# Any issues with protobuf-net and .Net 4?

Tags: .net-4.0, protobuf-net

Protobuf-net's [project page](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) talks about all .Net versions apart from 4.  Are there any issues with using protobuf-net under .Net 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

1. I haven't exhaustively tested it *specifically* for .NET 4 (since I've been busy hacking v2 into shape), and
2. I haven't updated the home-page in a while.

I am, however, not aware of any reason why this wouldn't work. I can spin up my VM and run the test-suite over .NET 4 if you really want...

Comment: Marc, thanks for the response. There's no need to run the test suite, I happy with your response above.  But, hey, it's kind of you to offer!

Comment: I'm running it on .NET4, have been for a few months with no issues.